# Where do imported React classes come from?

Tags: reactjs

When we import React and React.Component in react components like this,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Where do they come from? I looked in node_module folder's 'react' folder. But I have no idea where to look at in that folder. All I know is it comes from node_modules (I haven't installed react globally). Maybe this is a silly question. But please help me because I want to understand what really happens beneath the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `node_modules/react/index.js`
That's the entrypoint of the library. When you `import ... from "blah"` that means import from `blah/index.js`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.production.min.js');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js');
}
```

That changes what it exports based on prod/dev. Let's look at dev in `node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js`

And if you scroll  all the way down:

```js
...
exports.Children = Children;
exports.Component = Component; <---- THERE IT IS
exports.PureComponent = PureComponent;
exports.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED = ReactSharedInternals;
exports.cloneElement = cloneElement$1;
...
```

Then if we scroll up we can find the definition of Component:

```js
function Component(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context; // If a component has string refs, we will assign a different object later.

  this.refs = emptyObject; // We initialize the default updater but the real one gets injected by the
  // renderer.

  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;
}

Component.prototype.isReactComponent = {};
/**
 * Sets a subset of the state. Always use this to mutate
 * state. You should treat `this.state` as immutable.
 *
 * There is no guarantee that `this.state` will be immediately updated, so
 * accessing `this.state` after calling this method may return the old value.
 *
 * There is no guarantee that calls to `setState` will run synchronously,
 * as they may eventually be batched together.  You can provide an optional
 * callback that will be executed when the call to setState is actually
 * completed.
 *
 * When a function is provided to setState, it will be called at some point in
 * the future (not synchronously). It will be called with the up to date
 * component arguments (state, props, context). These values can be different
 * from this.* because your function may be called after receiveProps but before
 * shouldComponentUpdate, and this new state, props, and context will not yet be
 * assigned to this.
 *
 * @param {object|function} partialState Next partial state or function to
 *        produce next partial state to be merged with current state.
 * @param {?function} callback Called after state is updated.
 * @final
 * @protected
 */

Component.prototype.setState = function (partialState, callback) {
  if (!(typeof partialState === 'object' || typeof partialState === 'function' || partialState == null)) {
    {
      throw Error( "setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables." );
    }
  }

  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');
};
/**
 * Forces an update. This should only be invoked when it is known with
 * certainty that we are **not** in a DOM transaction.
 *
 * You may want to call this when you know that some deeper aspect of the
 * component's state has changed but `setState` was not called.
 *
 * This will not invoke `shouldComponentUpdate`, but it will invoke
 * `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate`.
 *
 * @param {?function} callback Called after update is complete.
 * @final
 * @protected
 */


Component.prototype.forceUpdate = function (callback) {
  this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this, callback, 'forceUpdate');
};
/**
 * Deprecated APIs. These APIs used to exist on classic React classes but since
 * we would like to deprecate them, we're not going to move them over to this
 * modern base class. Instead, we define a getter that warns if it's accessed.
 */


{
  var deprecatedAPIs = {
    isMounted: ['isMounted', 'Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in ' + 'componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.'],
    replaceState: ['replaceState', 'Refactor your code to use setState instead (see ' + 'https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3236).']
  };

  var defineDeprecationWarning = function (methodName, info) {
    Object.defineProperty(Component.prototype, methodName, {
      get: function () {
        warn('%s(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. %s', info[0], info[1]);

        return undefined;
      }
    });
  };

  for (var fnName in deprecatedAPIs) {
    if (deprecatedAPIs.hasOwnProperty(fnName)) {
      defineDeprecationWarning(fnName, deprecatedAPIs[fnName]);
    }
  }
}function Component(props, context, updater) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context; // If a component has string refs, we will assign a different object later.

  this.refs = emptyObject; // We initialize the default updater but the real one gets injected by the
  // renderer.

  this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;
}

Component.prototype.isReactComponent = {};
/**
 * Sets a subset of the state. Always use this to mutate
 * state. You should treat `this.state` as immutable.
 *
 * There is no guarantee that `this.state` will be immediately updated, so
 * accessing `this.state` after calling this method may return the old value.
 *
 * There is no guarantee that calls to `setState` will run synchronously,
 * as they may eventually be batched together.  You can provide an optional
 * callback that will be executed when the call to setState is actually
 * completed.
 *
 * When a function is provided to setState, it will be called at some point in
 * the future (not synchronously). It will be called with the up to date
 * component arguments (state, props, context). These values can be different
 * from this.* because your function may be called after receiveProps but before
 * shouldComponentUpdate, and this new state, props, and context will not yet be
 * assigned to this.
 *
 * @param {object|function} partialState Next partial state or function to
 *        produce next partial state to be merged with current state.
 * @param {?function} callback Called after state is updated.
 * @final
 * @protected
 */

Component.prototype.setState = function (partialState, callback) {
  if (!(typeof partialState === 'object' || typeof partialState === 'function' || partialState == null)) {
    {
      throw Error( "setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables." );
    }
  }

  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');
};
/**
 * Forces an update. This should only be invoked when it is known with
 * certainty that we are **not** in a DOM transaction.
 *
 * You may want to call this when you know that some deeper aspect of the
 * component's state has changed but `setState` was not called.
 *
 * This will not invoke `shouldComponentUpdate`, but it will invoke
 * `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate`.
 *
 * @param {?function} callback Called after update is complete.
 * @final
 * @protected
 */


Component.prototype.forceUpdate = function (callback) {
  this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this, callback, 'forceUpdate');
};
/**
 * Deprecated APIs. These APIs used to exist on classic React classes but since
 * we would like to deprecate them, we're not going to move them over to this
 * modern base class. Instead, we define a getter that warns if it's accessed.
 */


{
  var deprecatedAPIs = {
    isMounted: ['isMounted', 'Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in ' + 'componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.'],
    replaceState: ['replaceState', 'Refactor your code to use setState instead (see ' + 'https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3236).']
  };

  var defineDeprecationWarning = function (methodName, info) {
    Object.defineProperty(Component.prototype, methodName, {
      get: function () {
        warn('%s(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. %s', info[0], info[1]);

        return undefined;
      }
    });
  };

  for (var fnName in deprecatedAPIs) {
    if (deprecatedAPIs.hasOwnProperty(fnName)) {
      defineDeprecationWarning(fnName, deprecatedAPIs[fnName]);
    }
  }
}
```